# Return simple string in web API producing application/json

Tags: java, json, api, jersey, jax-rs

In the specification, the answer of the API is a simple string value, but the format is JSON.

I'm using Jersey.

If I construct my answer like that:

```
return Response.ok().entity("hello").build();
```

It's working, but for example, in the network view of Firefox, when I look at the answer, there is a JSON syntax error.
If I had some double quotes to the string like that:

```
return Response.ok().entity("\"hello\"").build();
```

There is no syntax error in Firefox, but I don't think it's a good way to do it.

Is there a good way to return a simple String value for an API producing some JSON?

Comment: _I don't think it's a good way to do it_. Why isn't it a good way?

Comment: The api should produce some JSON (application/json). 
But the specification for this call is :
 Object type:"string" 

 So i don't really know what i'm trying to do. I just want to know if there is a common practice.

Comment: @Kayaman `"hello"` is a valid JSON while `{"hello"}` is not a valid one.

Comment: Once `"hello"` is a valid JSON, there's nothing wrong with `Response.ok().entity("\"hello\"").build()`.

Comment: In case  do that, does any java JSON library provide a way to construct/deconstruct the string as JSON (adding the quotes) ? I don't find really elegant to add and remove quote by hand. I'm thinking to that for whose who will have to connect to the api.

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7705081/jax-rs-resteasy-service-return-json-string-without-double-quote "just looked into the JSON specification and from there it is written, that a value itself is not a valid JSON response (see http://www.json.org/)."

Answer (score 2):

if you're going to produces JSON then you have to return some Object or Collection, for example:

Hello.java

```
public class Hello{
  public String name;
  // getter setter
}
```

in YourRest.java

```
@GET
@Path("hello/{name}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String greeting(@PathParam("name") String name ){
  Hello hello = new Hello();
  hello.setName(name);
  return Response.ok().entity(hello).build();
}

@GET
@Path("people")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public ArrayList<String> peopleList(){
  List<String> people = new ArrayList<String>();
  Hello hello = new Hello();
  hello.setName("bloub");
  people.add(hello);
  hello.setName("Aime");
  people.add(hello);
  return Response.ok().entity(people).build();
}
```

http://localhost:8080/hello/bloub will return

```
{
"name" : "bloub"
}
```

http://localhost:8080/people will return

```
[
  {
    "name" : "bloub"
  },
  {
    "name" : "Aime"
  }
]
```

but if you want to return simple text then use `@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)`

for example:

in YourRest.java

```
@GET
@Path("hello/{name}")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String greeting(@PathParam("name") String name ){
  return Response.ok().entity("Hello, "+name).build();
}
```

http://localhost:8080/hello/bloub will return

```
Hello, bloub
```

Hope it helps